# Create Microsoft Team from Office365 group

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, skypedeveloper, microsoft-teams

I am facing a problem with creating a Microsoft Team from an Office365 group, I found a thread [Skype beta API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138723/create-microsoft-team-for-office-group-programmatically/45403982#45403982) but when I send the request I get an 'unauthorized' error. In the thread above Bernd told that he can provide a working sample.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

We don't currently have support for creating a Microsoft Teams team through any of the existing APIs (Microsoft Graph or other). We are working on a Graph API solution for this, so stay tuned.